# Counting how many occurences have been between datetimes

Tags: c#, datetime, event-log

```
 public void getCountUsers()
    {
        number = 0;
        //UserList = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
        UserList = new List<Users>();
        EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog();
        myNewLog.Log = "Security";
        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in myNewLog.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.InstanceId == 4624 && entry.TimeWritten.Date == DateTime.Today)
            {
                Regex ip = new Regex(@"192");
                Match IP = ip.Match(entry.ReplacementStrings[18]);
                Regex tester = new Regex(@"127");
                Match Tester = tester.Match(entry.ReplacementStrings[18]);
                if (Tester.Success || IP.Success)
                {
                    if (UserList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        bool check = false;
                        foreach (var user in UserList)
                        {
                            if (user.User == entry.ReplacementStrings[5])
                            {
                                user.countUsers += 1;
                                check = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!check)
                        {
                            Users u = new Users(1, entry.ReplacementStrings[5]);
                            UserList.Add(u);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Users u = new Users(1, entry.ReplacementStrings[5]);
                        //UserList = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
                        UserList = new List<Users>();
                        UserList.Add(u);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I use to count up how many users have been on one day. What I need to retrieve is how to filter the peak hour of the day, and how many people were online on that peak hour, and whom were in it.

(So for example 12:00 has 1 user and 15:00 has 15, 15:00 is the peak hour with 15 users in total)

If you need any more information, I would gladly edit.

Edit:

```
  foreach (EventLogEntry entry in myNewLog.Entries)
        {

            if (entry.InstanceId == 4624 && entry.TimeWritten.Date == DateTime.Today)
            {
                Regex ip = new Regex(@"192");
                Match IP = ip.Match(entry.ReplacementStrings[18]);
                string userName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(entry.ReplacementStrings[5]);

                Regex tester = new Regex(@"127");
                Match Tester = tester.Match(entry.ReplacementStrings[18]);

                if (IP.Success || Tester.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(number +
                     ". \t[Time of logon]\t\t" + entry.TimeWritten.ToLongTimeString() + "\t" + entry.TimeWritten.ToShortDateString() +
                     "\n   \t[Username-logon]\t" + userName +
                     "\n \t[IP-Adress]\t\t" + entry.ReplacementStrings[18] +
                     "\n----------------------------------------------------------------------- ");
                    number++;
                    //Console.WriteLine(entry.TimeWritten.ToLongTimeString() + " ; " + entry.TimeWritten.ToShortDateString() + " ; " + entry.ReplacementStrings[5] + " ; " + entry.ReplacementStrings[18]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Above outputs the first part, under outputs the second part.

```
public void showAmount()
    {
        int indexUsername = 0;
        ++indexUsername;
        Console.WriteLine("\nGebruikers:");
        foreach (var user in UserList.Where(u => u.User != "SYSTEM"))
        {
            string userName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(user.User);
            //Console.WriteLine(indexUsername + ". " +" \t " + userName +"" + user.countUsers);
            Console.WriteLine("#" +indexUsername + ".\t   {0} has been online {1}x times ", userName, user.countUsers);
            indexUsername++;
        }
    }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlikr.png)

Comment: I meant if you could show input and expected result because I can't seem to understand your question..

Comment: My apologies.
I don't input anything. I retrieve windows event logs from the logbook, which have corresponding dates names variables.

Comment: give an example for the output

Comment: Example: `The most amount of people online were on {time},   they were: {people's data as shown in first code}` (I'm terrible in markdown formatting, please excuse that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

```
public void getCountUsers()
{
    EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog();
    myNewLog.Log = "Security";

    var query =
        from EventLogEntry entry in myNewLog.Entries
        where entry.InstanceId == 4624
        where entry.TimeWritten.Date == DateTime.Today
        where new[] { "192", "127" }.Any(x => entry.ReplacementStrings[18].Contains(x))
        select new { entry.TimeWritten.Hour, User = entry.ReplacementStrings[5] };

    var result =
        query
            .GroupBy(x => x.Hour, x => x.User)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
            .Take(1)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Hour = x.Key,
                Users =
                    x
                        .GroupBy(y => y)
                        .Select(y => new Users(y.Count(), y.Key))
                        .ToList()
            })
            .First();

    Hour = result.Hour;
    UserList = result.Users;

}
```

`query` effectively replaces your code. It performs a loop over `myNewLog.Entries` and pulls out the `entry.ReplacementStrings[5]` value that you used to create the `Users` objects. I have added to this data the `entry.TimeWritten.Hour` value.

Now in the `result` variable I take the `query` and group the `User` property by `Hour`. Then I order by the descending count of users in each hour slot and when I `.Take(1)` I get the hour with the most users only. I then select the hour and do another grouping of user to create the `Users` objects - just like you did in your code - and finally I take `.First()` to get the highest populated hour out.

The final two assignments are only there to mimic your code.

---

Here's a way to produce your output string:

```
string output =
    String.Format(
        "Most active users were online on {0},{1} The users online at the peak was: {2}",
        TimeSpan.FromHours(result.Hour),
        result.Users.Count(),
        String.Join(", ", result.Users.Select(x => x.User)));
```

Comment: @308075 - Well, that's what this code does. Have you got a reference to `System.Linq`?

Comment: @308075 - The final assignment for `Hour`?

Comment: Yes, Hour = result.Hour gives that it doesnt exist in the context

Comment: @308075 - I've not declared the variable `Hour` because it seems that you have declared `UserList` as a field-level variable and I was going with the same idea for `Hour`. You just need to define it a `private int Hour;` in your class.

Comment: Please explain your code so I have a better understanding to it.

Comment: @308075 - Sure can. It'll probably be a bit later today when I have time.

Comment: I honestly hate the comments, but what I wanted to say is that I need a list like: Most active users were online on {Specific hour of the day, for example 13:00},{amount of users online} The users online at the peak was: {user data}

Comment: @308075 - I've added an output string to the solution.

Comment: Thanks alot! This is exactly what I was searching for! Do you think that in any other way I could change the hour from full 08:00:00 to just 8:00?

Comment: @308075 - Just put `TimeSpan.FromHours(result.Hour).ToString("h\\:mm")`.

Comment: How would I be able to get the first letter capitalized from result.Users.Select(x => x.User)? @Enigmativity Sorry for bothering you, but that's the last thing I need.

Comment: @308075 - Yes, with the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(...)` call. Why didn't you try that yourself?

Comment: I did try it out, it doesn't work since: I cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string' is what it gives. @Enigmativity

Comment: @308075 - Try `result.Users.Select(x => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(x.User))`.